# Long svn:mergeinfo on SVN directory properties

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, mergeinfo

It looks like every branch reintegration to trunk has caused an extra entry to be added in the trunk's svn:mergeinfo property. Is this SVN behavior or TortoiseSVN - and is there anything bad about it? I didn't think SVN used properties as a core part of functionality, only for additional things, so I was a bit surprised to see it.

Answer (score 3):

`svn:mergeinfo` is the property used by more recent versions of SVN to track which branches/revisions have been merged into a particular stream. This allows you not to have to think about it when doing said merges. The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) is a pretty good resource!

I'm pretty sure this isn't a TortoiseSVN thing.

Comment: True, from http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html: "The basic mechanism Subversion uses to track changesets—that is, which changes have been merged to which branches—is by recording data in properties. Specifically, merge data is tracked in the svn:mergeinfo property attached to files and directories."